# aws default IAM roles deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-opsworks

In my AWS account I had by default roles with names that start with aws-opsworks-service-role. By mistake I deleted these roles. Just wanted to know if these roles have any default usage by AWS which may cause problems now when they are gone? I did not create these roles and do not use the opswork service (at least not explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

It controls your delegation to the opsworks service. So you would end up with issues with opsworks itself not being able to display, and delegate some tasks involving the IAM roles, EC2 instances and ELB.

```
{"Statement": [{"Action": ["ec2:*", "iam:PassRole",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "elasticloadbalancing:*"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": ["*"] }]}
```

This is the policy. You can put it back easily enough.

Comment: is opsworks some default service I'm implicitly using or the problem will happen just if I explicitly add it? also how do I restore the roles?

Comment: Opsworks is a service of AWS. But to allow that service to create : IAM permissions, modify access etc for that stack on your behalf, you would need that. You maybe able to just CLONE the stack , and ask AWS to create the role for you. Then migrate the load balancers etc.

Comment: thanks, but is it an optional service or is it something that by default is used in my account? IOW will the lack of roles affect me only if sometime in the future I decide to activate the opswork service?

Comment: For a given stack, AWS wants access to some functionality in your account. It would need those access to control that specific stack. Create a new stack - it wont be affected. Trying to add EC2 servers might not work in the deleted stack because it wont have access to do something now.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted them and then re-added them by going to the OpsWorks console and creating a stack (which I then deleted afterward). I had no roles at all when i did this so it created the 2 used by opsworks. I suspect that if you have other roles already then specifying "New IAM Role" and "New IAM Instance Profile" will recreate the defaults